# Add custom action in content-type with a Net Client MTOM

Tags: c#, soap-client, service-reference, web-reference

I've a problem that I dont find any type of resolution..

I've to call a customer WDSL (and this works fine) with Net 4.6.1 and using VS 2022: I'd tryed to add WSDL with a service reference and then with a web reference but I've the same problem (so I've the object

When I made a call, that it's a MTOM call with a PDF, I've to add a custom action to content-type: I've tried everything (with servire reference OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders and with web reference I've tried to override GetWebRequest) but I'd no success.

I've to add ad image with what I've to do...but I cant find anything to do this...

Someone can help me?

Visual Studio 2022
Web Reference and Service Reference

Net 4.6